# Add customer behaviour to all spring data Jpa repositories in CDI context

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Am successfully injecting jpa repositories using CDI. I wanted to add custom behaviour(soft deletes) to all repositories. When using spring I can enable customer behaviour by specifying the repository base class

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = StagedRepositoryImpl.class)
```

How do I specify the same in CDI? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add custom behaviour to Jpa Repositories(in your case for delete),

**1.** Create a base repository like below:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

    @Override
    default void delete(T entity){
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

**2.** Now inherit Jpa Repositories from custom repository(i.e BaseRepository) like below:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends BaseRepository<Employee, Long> {
}
```

**3.** Inject your repository into Service class and call the delete method.

```
@Service
class EmployeeService {

    @Inject
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public void delete(Long id) {
        employeeRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Now whenever you call delete on repositories which are child of BaseRepository, your custom implementation for delete will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to add custom logic to your repositories:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Basically you create a custom repository named `{YourRepositoryName}Custom`

```
interface UserRepositoryCustom {
  public void someCustomMethod(User user);
}
```

And implement it:

```
class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {

  public void someCustomMethod(User user) {
    // Your custom implementation
  }
}
```

Your main repository should extend the custom one.
Hope this helps!