# How to set up custom behavior of spring data on a CDI environment

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, cdi

So, I have an application running on WildFly10, which uses JSF, Spring (DI), JPA, Spring Data;
Right now we're trying to move it to CDI and remove Spring(DI). For now we'll keep Spring Data.

So, I set up CDI and made an EntityManager producer.

```
@Produces
@Dependent
@PersistenceContext
public EntityManager entityManager;
```

So, I'm able to inject repositories with CDI and all.
However on my original environment we had a custom repository factory,that was defined in my SpringConfiguration like this:

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.foo.repository" }, **repositoryFactoryBeanClass=CustomJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class**)

So, the question is, how can I define this repositoryFactoryBeanClass=CustomJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class on a CDI environment?

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation doesn't allow the configuration of the `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean` as one can see from [the code where it gets instantiated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/cdi/JpaRepositoryBean.java#L74).

So I guess you have the following options:

1. reimplement the instantiation process.
2. open a [feature request](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA).
3. do 2. and 1. in a reusable way and submit the result as a PR for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to solve this problem I found that the custom impl was not being picked up.  The solution suggested in this question helped me however: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38541669/188624

Basically is uses Java8 default interface method to provide the additional functionality.  I had to use the "CDI.current().select" method to get hold of the entity manager though as property injection of course won't work.

I tested with Spring Data JPA 2.0.0